# How to redirect to another script if a function does not exist?

Tags: php

I am using a custom function and I would like to redirect to another script if this dynamic named custom function does not exist.
This snippet executes correctly because the function exists:

```
$a = '1';
call_user_func('prefix_'.$a);
function prefix_1(){}
```

In this case the function is not found and generates an error.

```
$a = '2';
call_user_func('prefix_'.$a);
function prefix_1(){}
```

I need the script redirects to another page, for example, using `header ('location: error.php');`.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: [function_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) ?

Comment: I already tried using this feature but I couldn't.

Comment: Why not? It works on my local dev box...

Comment: I don't know how. Could you show me, please?

Comment: Could you show us how you used function_exists()?

Comment: It's the best I can do:
if(!function_exists(call_user_func('prefix_'.$a))){
header ('location: error.php')
};

Comment: `function_exists()` just expects the name of the function **as a string** ... so `if(!function_exists('prefix_' . $a)) { ... }`

Comment: But the function is a user function, it needs to be evocated with "call_user_func"?

Comment: _“But the function is a user function, it needs to be evocated with "call_user_func"?”_ - and? What does that have to do with testing whether the function exists? Absolutely nothing, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Check function exist or not by using  **function_exists**

2.Using **IF** condition for redirecting error.php

3.If the function is not there condition goes to else part.

```
if(function_exists('prefix_'.$a)){
    call_user_func('prefix_'.$a);
}else{
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/error.php");
}
```